# HTML 5 video player doesn't gets played for android below 5.0 version in ionic app

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework

HTML 5 video player doesn't gets played for android below 5.0 version in ionic app. But the same codes works very fine for above 5.0 version.

Comment: can you put some code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can share you code is will be better.

try this

do not use the type attribute when calling the video, call manually the `play()` method using JavaScript.

ex :

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');

video.addEventListener('click',function(){
    video.play();
},false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app working fine with 5.0 or above version then may be you have set `targeted version 21` to your `android manifist` file

So try changing it minimum of `android version 2.2` (I think that's `API 8`) and then build the same will work on lower versions of android.